# How to type in a string that will be assigned to a variable?

Tags: java

I need my program to ask the user to type in a String which will be assigned to a variable eg:string in the case below so the array list can be searched for a String containing the String entered by the user.

```
public void search(){
    String string = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < wordArray.size(); i++){
        if (wordArray.get(i).contains(string) == true){
            System.out.println(wordArray.get(i));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No words match your search.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really the first thing that you will find in any java tutorial. I suggest you get yourself a book, or use google.

Answer (score 2):

If this is no gui application you can use [`System.in`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in).

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String string = s.readLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) api:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String string = s.nextLine();

....

s.close();
```

... or [`Console`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) from [`System.console()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29) :

```
String string = System.console().readLine();
```

(*You need to check that you get a console back from `System.console()` if you want to be sure!*)

Answer (score 1):

here's how you read from keyboard using JavaIo

```
  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);



    System.out.print("please type in a value ");

    String str = br.readLine();
```